# Concatenate strings in awk

Tags: awk

I have a log file which I need to "replay" on the server.

It contains entries like this:

```
Request:
        query: EXEC prc_insert_customer
        @param0: 110040851
        @param1: 137463
        @param2: user@example.com
        @param3: John
        @param4: Smith
        @param5: Some address
        @param6:
        @param7:
        @param8: Some city
        @param9: GBR
        @param10: POSTCODE
        @param11: (555) 123-45-67
Response:

...
```

I need to convert each chunk like that into

```
EXEC prc_insert_customer '110040851', '137463',  ..., '(555) 123-45-67'
```

I tried to use awk for that:

```
/EXEC prc_insert_customer/ {
        str = "EXEC prc_insert_customer";
}

str && /@param/ {
        if ($1 == "@param0:")
                sep = ""
        else
                sep = ","
        str = ((str) (sep) " '"($2) ("'"))
}

/^Response/ {
        if (str)
                print str
        str = ""
}
```

but the output I get is:

```
', '(555)'DE', '', 'Some', 'GBR0851
```

How do I get correct output?

I use `GNU Awk 4.0.0` on `Fedora 17`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the log files Windows based, then you are almost certainly dealing with side-effects (affects? ;->) of the evil ^M char. It can defintely produce problems as you're describing.

```
 sub(/^M/,"", $0)
```

should help.

Thats a real Ctrl-M char and not 2 chars'^','M', produced in a vi compliant editor by pressing Ctrl-V and tne Ctrl-M.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'd use `sub(/\r/, "", $0)` so you don't have a messy line break in your script. You could also use `/\015/`.

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation of this code snippet will do the trick:

```
BEGIN { processing = 0 }
/^Request/ { processing = 1 }
/^Response/ { processing = 0 }

{
    if (! processing)
        next

    if ($1 ~ /^@param/)
    {
        sep = ($1 == "@param0:" ? "" : ", ")
        rest = "'"
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
            rest = rest (i == 2 ? "" : " ") $i
        rest = rest "'"

        str = str sep rest
    }
    else if (str != "")
    {
        print "EXEC prc_insert_customer", str
        str = ""
    }
}
```

This prints for me:

```
 EXEC prc_insert_customer '110040851', '137463', 'user@example.com', 'John', 'Smith', 'Some address', '', '', 'Some city', 'GBR', 'POSTCODE', '(555) 123-45-67'
```

Tested with `awk version 20070501` and `GNU Awk 4.0.0` on Mac OSX.

Comment: It outputs logged lines followed by `, (555)123-45-67omstomer 110040851`

Comment: After the edit, the output changed slightly: `', '(555)123-45-67tyomer '110040851`. Still prepended with the log lines.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to avoid printing input lines when using the convenient `/from/, /to/` syntax.

Comment: The new version prints nothing to me. Which `awk` version are you using?

Comment: I tested it with `awk version 20070501` and `GNU Awk 4.0.0` and receive consistent output when invoking it like this: `awk -f test.awk < input.txt`.

Comment: If I move `/^Response/` block after the unconditional block it starts to work, however, it still outputs `', ' (555) 123-45-67tyer ' 110040851`. Something very weird is happening here. Could you please post base64-encoded input and script?